# How to create a DirectoryCatalog that will search sub directories for plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, catalog

So I have my directory catalog set up shown below:

```
DirectoryCatalog directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\Plugins");
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(directoryCatalog);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Which will find any .dll's in my `Plugins` folder that meet my import criteria. Now To prevent reference clashes in my plugins I would like to put each plugin in a seperate folder.

e.g.

> Plugins -> Plugin1 -> plugin1.dll
>
> ```
>       -> Plugin2 -> plugin2.dll
> ```

But my `DirectoryCatalog` doesn't find these plugins. Is it possible to implement this or do my plugin libraries have to be in that specified `.\Plugins` folder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can solve your problem by adding multiple `DirectoryCatalogs` to `AggregateCatalog.Catalogs` property like this:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
// iterate over all directories in .\Plugins dir and add all Plugin* dirs to catalogs
foreach (var path in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@".\Plugins", "Plugin*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(path));
}

_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
this._container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also this: 
 https://github.com/MefContrib/MefContrib/blob/master/src/MefContrib/Hosting/RecursiveDirectoryCatalog.cs

I found I needed to wrap the `_aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(catalog);` under `Initialize(...)` with a try/catch for `ReflectionTypeLoadException` to stop it throwing when it found non-plugin dlls.